# How to block access to files in folder in EC2 instance of AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

What I want to do is block access through url all the files inside a folder that is located in www / html / job within my EC2 instance in AWS where the source code of my application is located. By this I mean that a user can not download or view the files inside the folder, only accessing the URL in the browser, but within my application I can use these files without any problem.

Comment: Why would you keep files that should not be accessed by your web server (I guess Apache) in that directory?

Comment: Because I want to use them within my application but they are not accessed by any user through url.

Comment: Then don't put them in that folder. Put them somewhere else.

Comment: Maybe you can use a S3 Bucket dump all the files that you do not want any one to have access to and have you application call that bucket when you need those files. Restrict access depending on the IAM role.

Comment: @MarkusAppel 
How can I access this folder, if it is outside the folder that contains my source code?

Comment: @Mvram okay, let's make this clear. Create a new folder in, for example, your home folder. Put your source code there - everything you need for development. There should be zero dependencies to files in the `/www/` - folder. Now, whenever you want to publish something (maybe a file, maybe a new version of your javascript package, ...) copy these files to the `/www/` folder, effectively creating a "release" of whatever you do on your website. You don't have to copy manually - write yourself a simple bash script that transfers the files for you.

Comment: @Mvram This way, the `/www/` folder will only contain what you want users from the internet to see - hence the name of the folder!

Comment: @MarkusAppel the files I want to save are image files, or documents in general that users keep and that at some point I want to show them on my website, even though I want them not to be accessed through a public url. My question is, how can I show that image to my users that obviously will be logged in my application?

Comment: @Mvram Using authentication, for example cookies or signed URL's. That's not easy.